# BeforeBuild-AfterBuild targets not running

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I recently started migrating a MVC project from MVC5 to MVC6, everything works fine, except that the BeforeBuild/AfterBuild targets are not firing, I even opened the VS 2013 project (.csproj) in VS2015 and they run, but the ones I added to the new .xproj file in VS 2015 don't. Any idea on what could be happening?

Thanks!

project.json file

```
{
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"version": "1.0.0-*",

"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta6-*"
},

"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
},

"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta6",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta6"
        }
    } 
},

"publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
],
"exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
]
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the `project.json` file?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci done!

Comment: did you tried `dnu build` ?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET 5 doesn't use the csproj files anymore for build. They are only used by VS to display the project. Everything is in `project.json`.

You have to migrate those targets to `project.json` in order for them to run. Here's an example: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Project/project.json#L40-L47

Comment: I added the below to my projec.json file, but is not working so far, something I'm doing wrong?

`"scripts": {
        "postbuild": [
            "%project:Directory%/mkdir \"%project:Directory%/tstFolder\""
        ]
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you redefine the BuildDependsOn property for a 14.0 version tooling, it works fine. This is the strategy used by the VS targets.

```
<Target Name="CopyAutomapper">
   <ItemGroup>  
        <MySourceFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)\packages\AutoMapper\5.1.1\lib\net45\AutoMapper.dll"/>  
    </ItemGroup>  
    <Copy  
            SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"  
            DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\$(Configuration)\net461\win7-x64"  
        /> 
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>  
    <BuildDependsOn>  
        $(BuildDependsOn);
        CopyAutomapper;
    </BuildDependsOn>  
</PropertyGroup>
```